# Получение email писем в админ-панель

Tags: php, email

Друзья, интересует вопрос, возможно ли как то прикрутить в админку на php сервис приема писем(такой себе эквивалент почтового ящика). Кто может подсказать примерный алгоритм действий для получения сообщений? Интересует реализация самой идеи,как примерно это должно работать и что почитать по этой тематике,чтоб вникнуть. Нагуглить не могу. На англ язычниках не разобрался...а по русским мало инфы(хотя скорее всего не знаю,как правильно задать вопрос).Код постараюсь наплодить сам)учусь:))интересует сам метод. И большое спасибо за помощь заранее.

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически возможно читать и отправлять почтовые сообщения используя javascript
https://emailjs.org/
https://github.com/hiddentao/browsermail

Так же с помощью php можно читать и отправлять письма. Смотрите в сторону протоколов pop3, imap, sntp